# How to debug chrome extension with Intellij IDE?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij IDE and I was wondering if it's possible to debug Chrome extensions within the IDE.

I can start Chrome debugging session from the IDE, but I can't set any breakpoints.

The problem, if I understand it correctly, is that Chrome moves the JS files to the profile directory when I install the extension, so Intellij can't monitor them anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible right now. Actual problem — IDEA tries to connect, but special chrome extension page should be used. Vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9708