# Chrome extension development with live edit

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, phpstorm, liveedit

How do I get Chrome extension code to work with JetBrains Live Edit extension during development?

I'm trying to develop a Chrome extension in PHPStorm 8 and I would like for the code to work with the Live Edit feature the way a normal HTML/JS page would. However, I don't know how to configure it correctly so that I don't have to hit `Reload` on the Chrome extension page each time I make a change.

Comment: You have to manually reload the page to see the results - live edit doesn't force new code execution. To see the reference issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439811/what-kind-of-changes-does-chrome-pick-up-using-live-edit

Comment: I just found that the `Extensions Reloader` Chrome extension is a slightly less annoying option over having to go to the Extensions page in Chrome and clicking `Reload`. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Debugging/live editing Chrome extensions is not currently supported. Please vote for [WEB-9708](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9708)

Comment: Relevant SO question from that bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459554/how-to-debug-chrome-extension-with-intellij-ide